# Union of multiple arrays

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, union

I am using this code in order to create a certain number of arrays and fill them with certain numbers:

```
public void CreateVars() {
    System.out.println("Enter the numbers of variables: ");
    int i = s.nextInt();
    int[][] var = new int[i][];
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        System.out.println("Enter the number of values: ");
        int p = s.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter the numbers: ");
        var[j] = new int[p];
        for (int q = 0; q < p; q++) {
            int n = s.nextInt();
            var[j][q] = n;
        }
    }
}
```

How can I use the created arrays and do a union, for ex. A union B union C, since there is always a different number of arrays.

Thanks in advance

Comment: what it your desired result? a single one-dimensional array with all the numbers?

Comment: @TimothyTruckle Yes. If I do union of all the arrays, I want a single array displaying the union.

Comment: an array can _hold values_, it cannot _display values_.

Comment: @TimothyTruckle I would like to store all the values in a certain array and print that array.

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: @shmosel I do not know how to do a union of all these arrays.

Comment: There's no prepackaged way to do it. Think about what you want to do, break it down into steps, and convert your steps into Java statements. That's what coding is all about.

Answer (score 0):

1. change your method to return the created array.
2. create a second method that takes the 2-dimansional array as parameter and returns a 1-dimensional array. This will to the union as I will show later
3. use `Arrays.toString()` to display the arrays content via `System.out.println()`

in the new method create a variable for the 1-dimensionl target array.
then loop over the first dimension of the parameter:

```
for(int[] subArray : parameterArray)
```

in that loop create a new temporary 1-dimensional array variable with the size of the current size of the target variable plus the size of the current `subArray`.

```
int[] tempArray = Arrays.copyOf(targetArray,targetArray.length+subArray.length]);
```

iterate over the subArray and copy the current value at the appropriate position in the temp array.

when finished the inner loop store the tempArray as targetArray

```
targetArray = tempArray;
```